# Content Editor webpart added programatically not showing up on page edit

Tags: web-part, office-365, csom, content-editor-web-part

I added a webpart using the below process

Export your content editor web part and get the schema XML and follow the steps given in this link. [Programmatically add a web part to a page using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142209/programmatically-add-a-web-part-to-a-page-using-csom)

The content editor webpart I added is showing up on the pagem but not showing up on page edit.

I added on O365 site page through provider hosted app.

Comment: Prerequisite of SharePoint Online Client Components SDK is done?

Comment: could you please specify what all i need to check?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this very same issue. On the page you added the CEWP to, Edit the Page, click the Page tab, click Page Layout, then select Blank Web Part page under the Welcome Page category. Save the page and you should now see the CEWP.