# Programmatically Delete Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, csom

I have been able to add a web part, thank to [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142209/programmatically-add-a-web-part-to-a-page-using-csom), using code like:
`limitedWebPartManager.ImportWebPart(webPartSchemaXml)`

However now I'm not able to remove the Web Part anymore by Editing the Page,
because the Web Part is not visible in Edit mode (incidentally I don't know why).

So I'm trying to Remove the Web Part programatically, but LimitedWebPartManager doesn't offer a method like `RemoveWebPart`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DeleteWebPart method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpartdefinition.deletewebpart.aspx) of [WebPartDefinition class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpartdefinition_members.aspx) to delete web part from the page.

Demo:

```
class Program
{

                private class Configuration
                {
                                public static string ServiceSiteUrl = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>";
                                public static string ServiceUserName = "<user>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
                                public static string ServicePassword = "<password>";
                }

                static ClientContext GetonlineContext()
                {
                                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                                foreach (char c in Configuration.ServicePassword)
                                {
                                                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                                }
                                var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Configuration.ServiceUserName, securePassword);
                                var context = new ClientContext(Configuration.ServiceSiteUrl);
                                context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
                                return context;
                }


                static void Main(string[] args)  
                {  
                                var ctx = GetonlineContext();
                                var page = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/<SiteCollection>/SitePages/<page>.aspx");
                                LimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                                ctx.Load(limitedWebPartManager.WebParts,
                                                wps => wps.Include(
                                                wp => wp.WebPart.Title));

                                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                                if (limitedWebPartManager.WebParts.Count == 0)
                                {
                                                throw new Exception("No Web Parts to delete.");
                                }

                                WebPartDefinition webPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.WebParts[0];

                                webPartDefinition.DeleteWebPart();

                                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
}
```

Refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539301(v%3Doffice.14)#deleting-a-web-part-from-a-page

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-delete-a-webpart-using-client-object-model1

(Though these articles are for SharePoint 2010, they still have good information for SharePoint Online.)